# symfony2 twig and multiple levels of subfolders

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I find that including a template with this path works fine

```
{% include 'AcmeDemoBundle:TemplateArchive:view.html.twig' with {'data': c.data} %}
```

While this is seemingly not allowed:

```
{% include 'AcmeDemoBundle:TemplateArchive:6:view.html.twig' with {'data': c.data} %}
```

I am in other words trying to reach templates that I have sorted down into a subfolder structure in my bundle/resources/views/ folder.

If I am not allowed to drill any deeper than the regular one-level-inclusion as of my first line, is there another/better way of structuring these template files?

(the folder name '6' represents a template id from the database which I would like to include, it needs to be dynamic and sorted in folders nicely like that...).

I have tried naming my templates-folder 't6' but no difference, the "number with no leading letters" is not the issue here...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

What about

```
{% include 'AcmeDemoBundle:TemplateArchive:6/view.html.twig' with {'data': c.data} %}
```

Answer (score 6):

Both is working:

```
AcmeDemoBundle:TemplateArchive:6/view.html.twig
AcmeDemoBundle:TemplateArchive/6:view.html.twig
```

Comment: As ``Bundle:Subdir:filename.html.twig`` is what Symfony seems to expect (see [Symfony Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html)) I'd go with ``AcmeDemoBundle:TemplateArchive/6:view.html.twig``.

Answer (score 5):

As of Symfony 2.2 you can also use [Namespaced paths](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html):

```
{% include '@AcmeDemo/TemplateArchive/6/bar.html.twig' with {'data': c.data} %}
```

You can even define your own Namespaces:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/TemplateArchive": TemplateArchive
```

And then use it like:

```
{% include '@TemplateArchive/6/view.html.twig' with {'data': c.data} %}
```

This also works in controllers (with custom Namespaces too):

```
// TemplateArchiveController.php
return $this->render('@TemplateArchive/6/view.html.twig', ['data' => $c.getData()]);
```

From [[Symfony Cookbook: Namespaced paths](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html)]:

> As an added bonus, the namespaced syntax is faster.

Comment: Nice addition. Thanks

Comment: that alot better if you have bundles with lots of views in them plus you can stick the path in your bundle config

Comment: @DarkMukke How to you add the path in the bundle config? I've been trying to figure this out.

Comment: @DavidStone the same way described abovem but instead of doing it in app/config you do it in Bundle/Resources/config